# Can't change the time of the xAxes in the Chart.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, charts, chart.js

So I have ChartData Component. I am taking the data from an API, the data is being displayed through Chart. I have `determine Format Logic`, which it's the main thing is to determine the time of the data, I have 3 buttons, the thing that I am struggling to achieve is when let's say I wanna see the data of 7days when I press the button. I can see data is changing in the `yAxes` but I can't see time being changed on the`xAxes`, it's still set to hours, it should display the days.

ChartData

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import 'chartjs-adapter-moment';
import annotationPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-annotation';
import { Chart, registerables } from 'chart.js';
Chart.register(...registerables);
Chart.register(annotationPlugin);



const determineTimeFormat = (
  timeFormat: string,
  day: any,
  week: any,
  year: any
) => {
  switch (timeFormat) {
    case "24h":
      return day;
    case "7d":
      return week;
    case "1y":
      return year;
    default:
      return day;
  }
};

interface Props {
  data: any
}

const ChartData: React.FC<Props> = ({ data }) => {
  const chartCanvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement | null>(null);
  const { day, week, year, detail } = data;
  const [timeFormat, setTimeFormat] = useState("24h");
  const [isRebuildingCanvas, setIsRebuildingCanvas] = useState(false);
  
 

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsRebuildingCanvas(true);
  }, [timeFormat]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isRebuildingCanvas) {
      setIsRebuildingCanvas(false);
    }
  }, [isRebuildingCanvas]);

  useEffect(() => {
      if (chartCanvasRef && chartCanvasRef.current && detail) {
    const chartCanvas = chartCanvasRef.current
    if (isRebuildingCanvas || !chartCanvas) {
      return;
    }
  
    const chartInstance = new Chart(chartCanvasRef.current, {
      type: "line",
      data: {
        datasets: [
          {
            label: `${detail.name} price`,
            data: determineTimeFormat(timeFormat, day, week, year),
            backgroundColor: "rgba(134,159,152, 1)",
            borderColor: "rgba(174, 305, 194, 0.4",
          },        
        ],
      },
```

Options

```
options: {     
        plugins: {
          annotation: {
            annotations: {
           
            }
          }
        },
      
        animations: {
          tension: {
            duration: 1000,
            easing: 'linear',
            from: 1,
            to: 0,
            loop: true
          }
        },
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
          x: 
            {         
              type: 'time',          
            },  
        },
      }
    });
    return () => {
      chartInstance.destroy();
    }
  }}, [day, isRebuildingCanvas,timeFormat, week, year, detail]);
```

Rest of the Component

```
return (
    <div className='chart__container'>
    {renderPrice()}
      {isRebuildingCanvas ? undefined : (
        <canvas ref={chartCanvasRef}  width={250} height={250} id='myChart'></canvas>
      )}
      <button className='time__format' onClick={() => setTimeFormat("24h")}>24h</button>
      <button className='time__format' onClick={() => setTimeFormat("7d")}>7d</button>
      <button className='time__format'  onClick={() => setTimeFormat("1y")}>1y</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChartData;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a similar working example without reactjs. This can be useful for you to understand. You can refer the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Wahab896/7krxj0ut/395/) as well. A limitation that am currently facing is if there is data more than 100 then am getting errors while updating the data, performed slicing of data upto 100 to make it working.

```js
var coinData = {};
var fetchData = async() => {
  api = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3";
  id = "bitcoin";

  var [day1, week1, year1, detail1] = await Promise.all([
    fetch(api + `/coins/${id}/market_chart/?vs_currency=usd&days=1`).then(data => {
      return data.json()
    }),
    fetch(api + `/coins/${id}/market_chart/?vs_currency=usd&days=7`).then(data => {
      return data.json()
    }),
    fetch(api + `/coins/${id}/market_chart/?vs_currency=usd&days=365`).then(data => {
      return data.json()
    }),
    fetch(api + `/coins/markets/?vs_currency=usd&ids=${id}`).then(data => {
      return data.json()
    })
  ]);

  coinData = {
    day: formatData(day1.prices).slice(0, 100),
    week: formatData(week1.prices).slice(0, 100),
    year: formatData(year1.prices).slice(0, 100),
    detail: detail1[0]
  }

}

const formatData = (data) => {
  return data.map((el) => {
    return {
      t: el[0],
      y: el[1].toFixed(2)
    };
  });
};

const determineTimeFormat = (timeFormat) => {
  switch (timeFormat) {
    case "24h":
      return coinData.day;
    case "7d":
      return coinData.week;
    case "1y":
      return coinData.year;
    default:
      return coinData.day;
  }
};
var chartInstance;
fetchData().then(() => {
  /*   console.log(coinData); */


  var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer');
  chartInstance = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "line",
    labels: false,
    data: {
      datasets: [{
        label: `${coinData.detail.name} price`,
        data: determineTimeFormat('1d'),

        parsing: {
          yAxisKey: 'y',
          xAxisKey: 't',
        },
        backgroundColor: "rgba(134,159,152, 1)",
        borderColor: "rgba(174, 305, 194, 0.4)"
      }],
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        x: {
          ticks: {
            source: "data"
          },
          type: 'time',
          time: {
            unit: "day"
          }
        }
      },

    }
  });

});

function setTimeFormat(format) {
  Chart.instances[0].data.datasets[0].data = determineTimeFormat(format);
  Chart.instances[0].update();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.3.1/dist/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-moment@1.0.0/dist/chartjs-adapter-moment.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <button className='time__format' onclick="setTimeFormat( '24h')">24h</button>
  <button className='time__format' onclick="setTimeFormat( '7d')">7d</button>
  <button className='time__format' onclick="setTimeFormat( '1y')">1y</button><br><br>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you please update it in codesandbox.io/s/silly-glade-zguyt and paste it in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67689672/line-chart-is-not-being-displayed-in-chart-js?noredirect=1#comment119773798_67689672

Comment: No, because your code is based on reactjs. And I don't have much idea about it. That's why I have added the code using simple JavaScript.

Comment: Have you seen the question I have pasted, The problem I think is the x Axes because when a button is pressed the  Xaxes time should change accordingly to which button is pressed

Comment: On press of your button, your entire data is getting changed. So x and y both should be updated and since data is getting updated. The axes are also getting updated.

Comment: the actual  data is changing but the time (xAxes) its still set to hours

Comment: I have updated my answer, not it is by default on date and the dates will change on click button. Let me know if its correct.

Comment: Nothing, funny thing when I set the type to ```timeseries``` I get some drawing but that drawings are vertical not horizontal as they should be

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233101/discussion-between-wahab-memon-and-mura1).